# CoreBluetooth limitations?

Tags: objective-c, ios, bluetooth, core-bluetooth

I can't find any mention of the limitations on CoreBluetooth framework's read/write. Does anyone know what the speed & size limitations of these two functions are?

-(void) writeValue:(int)serviceUUID characteristicUUID:(int)characteristicUUID p:(CBPeripheral *)p data:(NSData *)data

-(void) readValue: (int)serviceUUID characteristicUUID:(int)characteristicUUID p:(CBPeripheral *)p

I need to know what the maximum size for data is and at what speed and how fast we can use these functions.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Sia

Comment: May I ask what device you want to connect to?

Comment: And that depends on the network latency at the time, strength of signal, environment. It seems hard to benchmark without a defined control environment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The connection/transfer speed is decided totally by the slave side, and not the master (your iPhone). Your iPhone app can request faster or slower transfer rates, but the slave decides if this will be allowed or not. 
This has been done since CoreBluetooth is made for use with **Bluetooth Low Energy**, and as the transfer rates increases, more battery is used. Since it is the manufacturers of the BLE devices that are guaranteeing for the battery life, and not the creator of the iPhone app, it has to be done this way.